# Actionbarsherlock bottom bar

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

How is it possible to show second action bar on a **bottom** of display? I want to be able to hide bottom bar from code according to needs when application is running.

I want to have there action buttons shown always, not only when there is no space on the top (I have top actionbar hidden, only tabs are there). Top and bottom bar should be independent.

Bottom bar si in the picture there: http://goo.gl/pFvHI

Thank you.

Comment: Use split action bar. Check ABS demo sample code/documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use in your AndroidManifest:

```
<activity
         android:name=".MyActivity"
         android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
         android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Key here is `uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"`.

Answer (score 2):

As per se it is not possible to split the action bar,as android handles it as a case per case basis based on screen dimensions.
Take a look here: [Have the split action bar..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199845/have-the-split-actionbar-display-twice-as-many-icons)

Most of the apps that have that behaviour have custom made views that show on screen.You could create a LinearLayout that has a method to add buttons and hide or show the view,and simply having a click listener on those views.Even google did this way on some of their apps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible Create `Options Menu` by using `SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM` for menu items.

like this

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { 
     int actionRoom = MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM;
     menu.add(Menu.NONE, ACCOUNTS_MENU, Menu.NONE, "Search")
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_account_list)
                .setAlphabeticShortcut('a')
                .setShowAsAction( accountRoom );

}
```