# Display buttons in main actionbar by using actionbarsherlock

Tags: android, android-widget, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have just started actionbar using actionbarsherlock. I have implemented it succesfully. I have used splitactionbarwhen narrow and splitted into main actionbar,tabbar,bottom bar. My question is how to add different icons in bottom bar and differnt icons in main actionbar?
I am restricting my app into portrait mode only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot add icons in main actionbar so instead we can use custom view in actionbar by using these statements

```
actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
actionbar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
actionbar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionbar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

View actionbar1 = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.action_custom, null);
actionbar.setCustomView(actionbar1);
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround might be in order, seeing [this other question right here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9329084/486063)

Fortunately though, mimicking the bottom bar seems fairly easy. Just use a LinearLayout with a defined height, aligned to the bottom with ImageButtons with equal weights.

Comment: Don't use splitActionBarWhenNarrow so it goes to the top instead.

Comment: but if there is a scroll view in that case the bottom bar will go down and the UI design looks awkward

Comment: jerieljan i want bottombar definately in my UI. so Is there any other way for me to solve my issue

Comment: in that case, I would use a vertical LinearLayout as the parent container, with a RelativeLayout or ScrollView and the bottom bar at the same level. http://pastebin.com/nLMS8FVs