# How to place both top and bottom action bar in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

Just like the below image i want to show my icon

Click [here](http://www.google.com.au/imgres?q=top+and+bottom+action+bar&um=1&biw=1366&bih=667&hl=en&sout=0&tbm=isch&tbnid=JOATcXNBHm5bvM:&imgrefurl=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327720/how-to-place-actionbar-items-in-main-actionbar-and-bottom-bar&docid=pi-QlVKNy-mu3M&imgurl=https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1VVk.jpg&w=288&h=512&ei=Eh-TUfaxA4uWrAeDGQ&zoom=1&iact=rc&dur=3556&page=1&tbnh=194&tbnw=109&start=0&ndsp=20&ved=1t:429,r:0,s:0&tx=28&ty=79)

I want to split top and bottom action bar in both landscape and portrait mode of smartphone.
The below code is working only in portrait mode(top and bottom action bar show) but not in landscape mode bottom action bar options are showed in top action bar.

```
 <application
    android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
```

I just want to show both action bar in both landscape and portrait mode of smartphone like above image.

Thanks

### Solution:

I have found the very nice solution for this problem, i think you will be also benefited using this solution

If you want both action bar will be separate then you should use Sherlock Action bar library. Using this library you can customize action bar as you like.
Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18052382/1121225)

Thanks

Comment: you should add the links which you have seen and didn't understand

Comment: Here is the link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571754/android-split-action-bar-with-action-items-on-the-top-and-bottom/13716962#13716962

Answer (score 1):

You want the [SplitActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077690/how-to-display-both-normal-and-split-actionbar), try this:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <application
    android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#uioptions

> Add a bar at the bottom of the screen to display action items in the
>   ActionBar, when constrained for horizontal space (such as when in
>   portrait mode on a handset). Instead of a small number of action items
>   appearing in the action bar at the top of the screen, the action bar
>   is split into the top navigation section and the bottom bar for action
>   items. This ensures a reasonable amount of space is made available not
>   only for the action items, but also for navigation and title elements
>   at the top. Menu items are not split across the two bars; they always
>   appear together.

Comment: I have used  android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" but it shows all action items in bottom bar not in top action bar. I want to fixed the top and bottom action items. They will not move from bottom to top.

Comment: look at the link i sent you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077690/how-to-display-both-normal-and-split-actionbar

Comment: Don't worry android geeks i have found the solution.

Comment: @Md.NaushadAlam  can you share the solution?

Comment: @LOG_TAG if you want both action bar top and bottom then i suggest you to use Sherlock Action bar library. Using this library you can customize action bar as you like. Thanks